# Angular 1.6 UI router can not load component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am updating angular 1.6 based web application from 'controller-based' to 'component-based app'.
Here is my code snippet:

dashboard-component.js

```
angular.module('app').component('dashboardComponent' , {
   template: '<a>Hello</a>',
   controller: function dashboardController() {
       var vm = this;
       console.log("dashboardController loaded");  
   }  
}
```

And app-router.js:

```
angular.module('app').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    .state('app', {
              url: '/app',
              abstract: true,
              templateUrl: 'framework/src/layout/template.html',
              data: {
                  BreadCrumbLabel: 'Home'
              }
    })
   .state('app.dashboard', {
              url: '/dashboard',
              component: 'dashboardComponent',
             /* templateUrl: 'app/components/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html',
              controller: 'dashboardCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'dashboardCtrl',*/
    }) 
});
```

I'd included them in index.html properly:

```
 <script src="app/app.router.js"></script>
 <script src="app/components/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.js"></script>
```

If I remove the comment in the app.router.js file and recover routing by 'dashboardController', it works correctly, but it doesn't work if I set routing entry to 'component'.
This is just a simple sample, and it seems component is not loaded, even console.log is not working.

Here is a plunkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/1aZ2aahTfT4AHIraWPCt?p=preview

Is this something you faced before? Would you like to help me?

Comment: share it in plunkr

Comment: @rijin - I'd updated the link